# What ratings are available for single sensors?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, equipment

The ultrasound sensor cyberware on page 452 of the core rulebook functions "exactly like the ultrasound sensor", but has a listed rating in the table of one to six.

According to page 445 and 446, single sensors are only available in ratings of 2-8, and are limited to a maximum rating of two for headware, which is the section that the ultrasound sensor cyberware falls under.

I'm confused by this discrepancy. Could someone explain the difference? What rating would an ultrasound sensor implant have compared to one built into headware like a helmet?

Additionally, I was under the impression that the rating of a sensor only functioned as a limit to electronic warfare perception tests, which can, RAW (445), only be used with sensor arrays. Does this mean that the rating of a sensor is completely irrelevant when not used in an array? What purpose does the different rating levels on the ultrasound sensor implant serve? Or what am I getting confused?

Answer (score 2):

Sensors are weird. I think an errata has been written for them, and if not I would hope one would be added soon.

I would go with the Rating 2 ultrasound sensor headware implant maximum. Maybe due to the sound possibility hurting or damaging your ears from inside your skull.

However, an ultrasound sensor inside a helmet wouldn't have to worry about the users protection as its outside of the user.

There is a rule about how a sensor needs to go into something, and the sensors rating can only go up to the container, this may be what is confusing you as it sure as hell confused me.

Comment: Can you back up your answer with any kind of official rule, or is this just what you would do?

Comment: I'm away from the rulebook now, but I would base it off of the sensor's container rule limiting the sensor for implants. The "a maximum rating of two for headware" is coming from there, although that most likely isn't explicitly stated